# How Hashset avoids duplicates

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

HashSet internally calling HashMap to avoid duplicates in the implementation

```
  public HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
    }

public boolean add(E e) { 
return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

For Example

Code:

```
Set hashSet = new HashSet();
hashSet.add("Abraham");
hashSet.add("Billy");       
hashSet.add("Billy");       
System.out.println("HashSet Value " +hashSet.toString());
```

Output:

```
HashSet Value [Billy, Abraham]
```

Comment: what about put method?

Comment: you mean All Set Implementation avoiding duplicates using Map      public boolean add(E e) {
 return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Map` interface, each key is also unique ([java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)):

> An object that maps keys to values. **A map cannot contain duplicate
>   keys**; each key can map to at most one value.

This means, the `HashMap` is already taking care of avoiding duplicate keys, which are the elements of the `HashSet`

Comment: If we restrict duplication in hashmap, whether it is equivalent to HashSet?

Comment: @Martin I do not follow what you are asking. A Map is "More powerful" than a Set, since it also maps each key to a value, but we could use a Map instead of a Set - it will just be less readable, but will still work.

Comment: I am trying to understand the purpose of HashSet

Comment: @Martin It's more readable to use a `HashSet` than a `HashMap` with dummy value, and it implements the `Set` interface.

Comment: Will the downvoter please elaborate what's wrong with the answer?